# Redirecting user links to their profile2 pages

Tags: 7, users

I'm using the profiles2 module for my user profiles.  I want to keep the user accounts hidden, and instead, use the profiles for public viewing.  I disabled user pictures in users, and added an image field to the profile entity.  When users post comments, the links point back to the user account.  How can I change that behavior so links point back to that user's profile page?  Also, how can I display the profile pics for these comments?  Essentially, I'm wanting the normal user functionality to occur with profiles instead of users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of

[`hook_preprocess_username`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_username/7) (make links go to profile path)

Something like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
  $account = $variables['account']
  if($profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'profile_type')){
    // This gets passed onto theme_username
    $variables['link_path'] = 'user/' . $variables['uid'].'/profile/path';
    // Possibly:
    // $type = $profile->type();
    // $path = profile2_page_get_base_path($type) . '/' . $account->uid
  }
}
```

and then the picture override in

[`hook_preprocess_user_picture`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7) (override user picture)

Something like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_picture(&$variables) {

  $account = variables['account'];
  if($profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'profile_type')){
    // You could use a custom 'display' parameter, e.g image_style
    $image = field_view_field('profile2', $profile, 'field_image');
    $variables['user_picture'] = render($image);
  }

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks David!  (note to other viewers: don't forget the '&' in the variables argument on the preprocess_username fx).  Also, profile2_page_get_base_path() expected an object.  I'll have to look at it later (or post if you know).

Comment: For some reason, the field_view_field call isn't working right.

Comment: To clarify, the field is populated, but the text 'Array' is rendered where the image should be.

Comment: @vintorg it needs `$variables['user_picture'] = render($image);` - answer updated

Comment: Answer also updated to use `$type = $profile->type();` for `profile2_page_get_base_path` object param

Comment: That did 'er.  One thing I am struggling with in Drupal is when something gets themed, rendered, etc.  I wish there was a comprehensive diagram that helped break that down.  Anyway, thanks again David!

Comment: I'm having problems with this, can you please clarify what you did to make this work? the preprocess doesn't seem to be working when I've pasted it in my template.php and replaced the name with my theme. Thanks :)

Comment: Fixed it! this is my code :  `function YOURTHEME_preprocess_username(&$vars)
{
   $account = $vars['account'];
   if ($profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'machine_name_of_your_profile'))
   {
      $type = $profile->type();
      $vars['link_path'] = profile2_page_get_base_path($type) . '/' . $account->uid;
   }
}`
, as taken from http://www.socialseomanagement.com/drupal-howto-redirecting-user-account-links-users-profile-page . I've had to clear my cache too.

Answer (score 2):

Drilling down a bit, the picture there is generated inside `comment.tpl.php` by the `user-picture.tpl.php` template, inside of which it relies upon the `$user_picture` variable.

So, the easiest way might be to put something along these lines in your theme's `template.php`...

```
YOURTHEME_preprocess_user_picture(&$variables) {

  $account=$variables['account'];

  $variables['user_picture'] = // whatever you want it to be instead of the default

}
```

...with whatever logic you need based upon the user information passed in via the `$account` variable.

This would also have a possible added benefit of overriding this everywhere a user picture is similarly themed.

Comment: Excellent jimajamma.  Can I also modify the user links to point to the profile pages instead of user accounts from template.php?

Comment: A small typo on the second line of the function, should be `$variables['account']`.

Comment: good catch, fixed up.  thx!